# How to store each array value with their keys in php

Tags: php, arrays, key, array-merge, array-push

I want to store my variables in an array alongside their keys like :

```
filter : [ 
"0" : "test",
"1" : "you",
"2" : "php"
]
```

I have `filter[]` array in the first place and each time with update request I want to add a value to this array with it's key, automate created key.

I've tried this two methods but they are not storing variable keys:

```
//$seat_filters = filter array fetched from db

$filters = array($request->input('filter'));

$filters_array = array_merge($seat_filters, $filters);
```

When I check the result of `$filters_array` I get :

```
filter : [
"test",
"you",
"php"
]
```

Same thing happens in below method of storing values in array :

```
 array_push($seat_filters ,$request->input('filter'));
```

Only second method is shorter.
FYI : This results are in JSON format.

Comment: If array keys are numeric and __ordered__ - json ignores them.

Comment: Who voted down ? why ?

Comment: @u_mulder When I unset one of this arrays element then I get their keys with their values in json. why is that

Comment: Because when you `unset`, order of indexes is broken

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for the tip , so is there any way to store their keys as this way ?

Comment: @u_mulder how to accomplish this when I don't know their indexes ? foreach loop will do the trick ?

Comment: Why do you even care about numeric indexes?

Comment: it's important for me, I need their indexes because I give them in result to user which they can be able to edit or delete each element of this array using that index. and also because when I remove any element from this array, elements gets their keys and I'm returning this values to user and my data structure are not matching.

Comment: If you know a way to remove an element from an array without getting their keys , I mean removing an element without setting any keys to remaining elements , That'll do the trick for me.

Comment: Then restructure your data to something like: `filter: [["0" : "test"], ["1" : "test1"]],`. So as to store your ids implicitly

Comment: @u_mulder this is exactly what I want but my problem is this array is dynamic and is not static, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Created a kind of anwser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I don't understand what all these for, but still some advices.

So you have an array like:

```
$a = ["test","you","php"];
// though it's indexes are not visible - they exist
$filter = [];
// you can see indexes in this `foreach`
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo 'Key is ', $k, '; value is ', $v;
    // now you can add both values to your filter
    $filter[] = [$k, $v];
}
print_r($filter);
echo json_encode($filter); // [[0,"test"],[1,"you"],[2,"php"]]
```

Comment: I have also found a solution for my problem : I can give this values custom keys like : f1 or f2 ...

Comment: if ((array_search($request->input('filter'),$seat_filters)) == false) {

                $count = count($seat_filters);
                $filters_array = array_merge($seat_filters ,array("f".$count++=>$request->input('filter')));
            }

Answer (score 1):

To save your key in an array:

```
  $output = array_map(function($v, $k){return[$k, $v];}, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method in php.

```
array_combine()
```

Comment: If possible use a counts[] array variable, increment it too. Then use array_combine() method.